# locating "irbrc" file on a Mac

Tags: ruby

I see a lot of cool stuff I can add to my Ruby console. For example, a good list is 
"[My .irbrc for console/irb](http://drnicwilliams.com/2006/10/12/my-irbrc-for-consoleirb/)".

I googled, but all I found is weblogs saying what gems people add to their .irbrc. No one is saying where to find it.

I cannot find "irbrc".
I opened my home folder and, if I type IRB, it goes to the Ruby console, but I can't find this file.
Can someone help me locate it?

Comment: hmm this one says just create it http://girliemangalo.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/using-irbrc-file-to-configure-your-irb/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a irbrc dotfile so you will need to `ls -a` in your home directory to find it. If it isn't in there, simply create a .irbrc file.

Mine's pretty simple but this is what I have in it:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'ap'

require 'irb/completion'
ARGV.concat [ "--readline", "--prompt-mode", "simple" ]

module Readline
  module History
    LOG = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-history"

    def self.write_log(line)
      File.open(LOG, 'ab') {|f| f << "#{line}\n"}
    end

    def self.start_session_log
      write_log("\n# session start: #{Time.now}\n\n")
      at_exit { write_log("\n# session stop: #{Time.now}\n") }
    end
  end

  alias :old_readline :readline
  def readline(*args)
    ln = old_readline(*args)
    begin
      History.write_log(ln)
    rescue
    end
    ln
  end
end

IRB::Irb.class_eval do
  def output_value
    ap @context.last_value
  end
end

Readline::History.start_session_log

require 'irb/ext/save-history'
IRB.conf[:SAVE_HISTORY] = 100
IRB.conf[:HISTORY_FILE] = "#{ENV['HOME']}/.irb-save-history"

IRB.conf[:PROMPT_MODE] = :SIMPLE
require 'irb/completion'
```

Comment: thanks, will use your file, there are pretty good stuff in it. But still a question: so with setting this file, I don't need to like load them anymore in IRC? they just work? what are some reasons for it not to load successfully?

Comment: Hmm, my file may not load correctly because I'm requiring the awesome print gem (require 'ap') so you'll need to do a 'gem install awesome_print' but other than that I think it should all work. You'll just need to type irb from your command prompt and it should all be there.

Comment: A "dot file" can be anywhere. The "dot file" convention means it's hidden and not normally displayed, but it doesn't necessarily mean it's in the home directory. Check Git's `.git`, and SVN's `.svn` folders, which can be anywhere the project is.

Comment: Right but the convention for irbrc dotfile, which the question is about, is to be in the home directory. :) Obviously other dotfiles, like the .git ones you mention, can be in other locations.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to find the file`.irbrc` in your home directory, simply create it in your home directory and fill it with some lines such as:

```
require "irb/completion"
```

Then your irb will automatically load completion module when you launch irb.

PS: it also works for UNIX/Linux system.